# Debezium: Replicating data from Oracle read-only database

Tags: debezium, debezium-engine

My use case is to capture CDC data from Oracle read-only PDB database using Debezium. When I tried installing and run Debezium, it's throwing below error message

Can someone please help with the correct Debezium config?

```
ORA-16000: database or pluggable database open for read-only access



at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CTTIoer11.processError(T4CTTIoer11.java:628)
at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CTTIoer11.processError(T4CTTIoer11.java:562)
at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4C8Oall.processError(T4C8Oall.java:1145)
at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CTTIfun.receive(T4CTTIfun.java:726)
at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CTTIfun.doRPC(T4CTTIfun.java:291)
at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4C8Oall.doOALL(T4C8Oall.java:492)
at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CCallableStatement.doOall8(T4CCallableStatement.java:144)
at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CCallableStatement.executeForRows(T4CCallableStatement.java:1034)
at oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleStatement.executeSQLStatement(OracleStatement.java:1507)
at oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleStatement.doExecuteWithTimeout(OracleStatement.java:1287)
at oracle.jdbc.driver.OraclePreparedStatement.executeInternal(OraclePreparedStatement.java:3735)
at oracle.jdbc.driver.OraclePreparedStatement.execute(OraclePreparedStatement.java:3933)
at oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleCallableStatement.execute(OracleCallableStatement.java:4279)
at oracle.jdbc.driver.OraclePreparedStatementWrapper.execute(OraclePreparedStatementWrapper.java:1010)
at io.debezium.connector.oracle.logminer.LogMinerHelper.executeCallableStatement(LogMinerHelper.java:701)
at io.debezium.connector.oracle.logminer.LogMinerHelper.createFlushTable(LogMinerHelper.java:105)
at io.debezium.connector.oracle.logminer.LogMinerStreamingChangeEventSource.execute(LogMinerStreamingChangeEventSource.java:122)
at io.debezium.connector.oracle.logminer.LogMinerStreamingChangeEventSource.execute(LogMinerStreamingChangeEventSource.java:63)
at io.debezium.pipeline.ChangeEventSourceCoordinator.streamEvents(ChangeEventSourceCoordinator.java:159)
at io.debezium.pipeline.ChangeEventSourceCoordinator.lambda$start$0(ChangeEventSourceCoordinator.java:122)
at java.base/java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:515)
at java.base/java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:264)
at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1128)
at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:628)
at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:829)
Caused by: Error : 604, Position : 0, Sql = CREATE TABLE LOG_MINING_FLUSH(LAST_SCN NUMBER(19,0)), OriginalSql = CREATE TABLE LOG_MINING_FLUSH(LAST_SCN NUMBER(19,0)), Error Msg = ORA-00604: error occurred at recursive SQL level 1
ORA-16000: database or pluggable database open for read-only access



at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CTTIoer11.processError(T4CTTIoer11.java:632)
... 24 more
```

Answer (score 0):

As of version 2.2 there is a new property for supporting read only in Debezium:

```
internal.log.mining.read.only=true
```

Reference:
https://debezium.io/blog/2023/04/20/debezium-2-2-final-released/